# Uniform continuity in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

How could I verify if  $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is uniformly continuous in $D(0,1)$? (i.e $|z|$ strictly smaller than $1$)

I started by using the usual definition, with $|z-z_o|< \delta$, I want to prove that $|f(z)-f(z_o)|= |\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n - z_o^n| < \epsilon$.

Any ideas?

Comment: This function is not uniformply continuous on $D(0,1)$. You have to consider $D(0,\delta)$, for some $\delta<1$.

Comment: could you give me more details?

Comment: If you take $\delta < 1$, then $1/(1-z)$ is defined on $\overline{D}(0, \delta)$, which is compact. In this case continuity implies uniform continuity. Things work well away from $1$, the problematic point.

Comment: Given the appropriate choice for $\delta$, now all you have to show is continuity on $\bar{D}(0,\delta)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is not uniformly continuous. Any uniformly continuous map must take a Cauchy sequence into another Cauchy sequence. The sequence $z_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ is Cauchy, but it's image is $f(z_n) = n$, which is not Cauchy.

Comment: even if zn is in the complex plane?

Comment: The fact that uniformly continuous maps take Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences, and that every convergent sequence is Cauchy is valid for arbitrary metric spaces. We have $z_n \to 1$, don't we? :)

Comment: Glad to help! If the problem is solved, you can always mark the green checkmark near the answer, to keep things organized, too.

Comment: but doesnt continuous maps take cauchy sequence to cauchy sequences too? so does that mean the function is not continuous too, which i would find quite weird.

Comment: No, continuous maps need not take Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences. Continuity being uniform is essential here. A counter-example might be something like $\sin(1/x)$, with some sequence that goes to zero.